# Read excel file and display in textarea or store as array in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, jqgrid

Is there a way I can an excel file using javascript and store a single column (with name or index) as an array in javascript?

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not write any code. After a little search on the internet. I found this this library to read excel files with javascript - https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx . Hope it helps for anyone who needs a solution.